# OAuth2 logout not working in Spring Security using Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, okta, spring-oauth2

I have one Spring Boot Webflux application using Spring Security. It is using `OAuth2` for Authentication. `Login` is working fine. But `logout` is not working. I can go to `/logout` page and click `Logout` button and it takes me back to `Login` page again which is good but when I go back to page that needs authentication it automatically logs me back in without prompting me to sign in again.

Here is my code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties;

    @Autowired
    public OAuth2SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties) {
        this.authenticationProperties = authenticationProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
            .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> {
                authorizeExchangeSpec.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll();
                authorizeExchangeSpec.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/assets/**").permitAll();
                authorizeExchangeSpec.anyExchange().authenticated();
            })
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
            .logout(logoutSpec -> logoutSpec.logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler()))
            .build();
    }

    public OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        var successHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository());
        successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}");

        return successHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(this.oktaClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration oktaClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("okta")
            .clientId(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getClientId())
            .clientSecret(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getClientSecret())
            .redirectUri("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
            .scope(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getScope())
            .authorizationGrantType(new AuthorizationGrantType("authorization_code"))
            .authorizationUri(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getAuthorizationUri())
            .tokenUri(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getTokenUri())
            .userInfoUri(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getUserInfoUri())
            .jwkSetUri(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getJwkSetUri())
            .userNameAttributeName("email")
            .clientName("okta")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to fix this.

Comment: your `logoutHandler` does not call the authorization server (Okta) to terminate the user session there (when he tries to login again on Okta, it happens silently) => change your logout handler to call Okta's logout endpoint. Note that for OIDC authorization servers, you may configure a logout "success" handler (`OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler`) and keep the default logout handler.

Comment: Would you please provide an example or link somewhere if possible. That will help me a lot. I tried to look for it in Spring site but could not find one.

Comment: `OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler` does not accept `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` which is what I am using here.

Comment: Yes, `OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler` constructor does expect `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository`. Sample [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/eda1904b4186a2eeb3e2b116809ea12a8074115a/samples/tutorials/reactive-client/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials/WebSecurityConfig.java#L67) (and you might find the reset of [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/reactive-client/src/main/java/com/c4soft/springaddons/tutorials) useful)

Comment: Thank you very much for that link. I really appreciate it. As per your suggestion I added `OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler` in `ogoutSuccessHandler` but it is still not working. I updated my question code snippet as well to reflect it.

Comment: Does the `.well-known/openid-configuration` contain an `end_session_endpoint` as per [RP initiated logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) spec? If it doesn't, just follow the `reactive-client` tutorial linked just before, it contains detailed instructions for non standard logout...

Comment: It is `Okta` so I would say yes but where can I check that information.

Comment: `${issuer-uri}/.well-known/openid-configuration`, and Okta doc, off-course. The only experience I have with Okta is through their Auth0 offer in which the OIDC compliance for logout is an opt-in (you have to specifically enable some configuration options). So yes, you should open the doc and check. **Then refer to the tutorial linked** for step by step instructions as you seem to have little experience with OAuth2 and Spring.

Comment: I had to set `end_session_endpoint` metadata now its working thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to resolve this issue it looks like when you are manually configuring `ClientRegistration` `end_session_endpoint` is not set as a result RP initiated logout was not working. Solution was to set that variable like this.

```
private ClientRegistration oktaClientRegistration() {
    return CommonOAuth2Provider.OKTA
        .getBuilder("okta")
        .clientId(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getClientId())
        .clientSecret(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getClientSecret())
        .authorizationUri(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getAuthorizationUri())
        .redirectUri("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
        .scope(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getScope())
        .tokenUri(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getTokenUri())
        .userInfoUri(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getUserInfoUri())
        .jwkSetUri(authenticationProperties.getOauth2().getClient("okta").getJwkSetUri())
        .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
        .clientName("Okta")
        .providerConfigurationMetadata(Map.of("end_session_endpoint", "OKTADOMAIN/oauth2/default/v1/logout"))
        .build();
```

This was the case with `Okta` other OAuth provider may need different solution.